# [Python]Conversion issue: Float --> Bytes and viceversa

Tags: python, sockets, numpy, server, client

i'm struggling with something i cannot solve.
I'm developing a Client - Server app, in python ofc, i need to send some "float type" data but sock.sendto needs a "bytes type" variable to be sent.
I tried struct.pack, i tried numpy.array(this one makes me send a whole array, seems to be the best module in this case) both of them work, i can send the data i need in a "bytes type" format.
The real issue is Server sided, i can't convert the data received(in bytes) into a float.
I tried this:
1) Cast: float(data) ofc it didn't work
2) "".join the variable and then cast it using float(data) ofc this didn't work too

So i'm quite confused. Any idea? I really need to read a float server side.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# sender side
data = struct.pack('!d', 3.1415)  # float -> bytes

# receiver side
x = struct.unpack('!d', data)  # bytes -> float
```

`struct.unpack` returns a tuple of unpacked values. With `x[0]` you get the first (and in this case only) value, which is the float you want.

**Edit:** Note that python floats are actually doubles and should therefore be packed as such.

Comment: Thank you.
Forgot to unpack. That was the perfect solution :D

Comment: I did actually run it with `'!d'`. I've ammended the post.

Comment: @mhawke Why did you delete your answer? I think apart from the precision issue it was better than mine because it discussed other options.

Comment: @kazemakase: because those answers were based on ignorance of the double struct format specifier and are therefore irrelevant. Despite being deleted the post is still visible, and might be of value to others falling into the same trap. I hope that the OP has seen your update.